# The recommended way to integrate ROS and GAZEBO to build a robot model

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, sdf, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I know that there is a plenty of treads about this subjects but none of them really answered my doubts. But first, a little contextualization.

I am using ROS a while and currently I consider myself an intermediate ROS user. Recently I joint a project where I will be developing and implementing algorithms for an autonomous  airship. In the scope of the project, there is not an airship simulator integrated with ROS and since it would be a value tool to have I decided to develop one via GAZEBO. In GAZEBO I consider myself a beginner.

For now I studying a lot of documentations and tutorials and so I am feeling somewhat drowned by all this new information. So I decided to open this thread as an way to consult some expert in ROS and GAZEBO. Here goes what I want and my questions:

- A want to develop o model of a balloon (let, for now, forget about airship) which I can simulate via GAZEBO and I can
  interact via ROS. With GAZEBO I expect to use all, or most of all, its  simulations tools. In special I want to be able to use the plugins Aerodynamics and Hydrodynamics. With ROS I expect to send control commands to the model and receive sensors information from it

> My question is, since for me appears that everything comes from this, the robot model should be build upon the **SDF** or **URDF** format to I be able to achieve the detailed functionalities? Because, from what I read, if I use SDF I easily will be able to use the GAZEBO tools and plugins but, in the other hand, I will have difficult to interact with it via ROS. If I use URDF I will be able to interact with it via ROS but I may face some issues with GAZEBO or its plugins.  So, what should I work with?

I know that this thread seems a little broad, but I just want an orientation to where to start. For example, If in a few days I  make a square floats in GAZEBO that I can move it via ROS it will be a great achievement!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272977/the-recommended-way-to-integrate-ros-and-gazebo-to-build-a-robot-model/) by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2017-10-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-13**:
Not an answer, but your question reminded me of  [From simulation to the field: Learning to swim with the AQUA robot](https://roscon.ros.org/2017/presentations/ROSCon%202017%20Simulation%20to%20the%20Field%20with%20AQUA.pdf), one of the presentations at ROSCon'17. It's about underwater robotics, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-13**:
.. but a lot of it is probably applicable to your situation as well (similar dynamics?).

The team of the presenter implemented a full control stack + model + gazebo plugins for their robot. Perhaps you can use that as inspiration for your own work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-13**:
Be sure to check the [video](https://vimeo.com/236138182) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm by no means an expert, but so far I've found the ROS+Gazebo path to be pretty productive. All of the robot logic is in ROS, and the simulation is run in Gazebo. I was able to bring up my robot before I had settled on a hardware design, and Gazebo saves me tons of testing time as I add features.

A few caveats:

(1) the URDF-to-SDF conversion process is a bit tricky. In my workflow I found it helpful to check the intermediate SDF output to make sure I was using the gazebo tags correctly in my URDF file (I wasn't.)

(2) The aerodynamics and hydrodynamics plugins are good starting points, but there's a lot that they don't do. There are some [really nice](https://github.com/uuvsimulator/uuv_simulator) [models to look at](https://github.com/freefloating-gazebo/freefloating_gazebo_demo), but it also helped me to write a few simple plugins to get familiar with how Gazebo worked.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1